# Android Custom Listview item select with Tabhost

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost

I am new to Andoid and still learning.
I am trying to select an item in a custom listview within a TabHost where there are three files.  one for the Tabhost,  One for a standard listview,  And one for a modified listview.
The code added below displays correctly.  I am just unable to figure out how to long click on an item in the displayed list so i can then remove it from its list.

First Activity

```
public class View_categories extends TabActivity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_edit_cat);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Category").setContent(new Intent(this, Category.class)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Sub_Category").setContent(new Intent(this, Sub_category.class)));        
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); 

  }

}
```

Second activity in seperate file.

```
public class Category extends ListActivity {

  List<String> cCategory;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    catList(); //Loads list
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,cCategory));

  }
}
```

Third activity in third file.

```
public class Sub_category extends ListActivity {


List<String> sSub_cat;
List<String> sCategory;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){        

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    subList();      //loads list
    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.textView1,sCategory));

}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_cat_list, parent, false);

        TextView cat_v = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView sub_v = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);           
        cat_v.setText(sCategory.get(position));
        sub_v.setText(sSub_cat.get(position));  

        return row;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: In `Category` and `Sub_category` just register your listview with `onLongItemClickListener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the following code after setListAdapter()
I originally put the first line before the setListAdapter() and was getting errors.

```
    ListView list = getListView();      
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(Category.this, "test toast Cat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }

    });
```